# Finitely generated ring.

Tags: ring-theory, finitely-generated

> Let $R$ be a finitely generated ring. Then is it true that $R^2$ is also finitely generated?

My Attempt: I do not find a counterexample. I think it is true. Please someone help me to prove that $R^2$ is finitely generated.

Comment: Please define "finitely generated ring".

Comment: Having finite number of generators.

Comment: it may be 1 or more but a finite number

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ has one generaor $1$ and $\mathbb{Z^2}$ is generated by (1,0) and (0,1).

Comment: Do you know finitely generated ideal?Every ring is ideal of itself.So it is equivalent to finitely generated ideal.

Comment: @user163993 regarding as an ideal, this is presumably not what you had in mind, as every ring is generated by $1$ as an ideal over itself.

Comment: @BillDubuque Is a finitely generated ring a ring which is finitely generated as a $\mathbb Z$-algebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A\subseteq R$ be a set such that no proper subring of $R$ contains $A$. Then $B:=\{\,(a,1)\mid a\in A\,\}\cup\{\,(1,a)\mid a\in A\,\}$ is a subset of the ring $R^2$ having the same property (I assume $1\in R$). Note that if $A$ is finite than $B$ is also finite.

Comment: Very nice,you take the maximal subset.Thanks